# Publishing Django app writter in Aptana to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, aptana

I am new to almost everything web development related. I am using Aptana studio 3 on a Mac and have built a very basic app using Django that works as expected on the Django development server provided with Django. I now want to try out publishing it to a 'real' server. I found out that Aptana has some integration with Heroku and so decided to try and publish there.

On the app explorer in Aptana I am locating my django project (named 'mysite') on the dropdown and then clicking the publish button to run the 'Web Deployment Wizard'. After selecting that I want to publish on Heroku and filling in the details of my Heroku account I click finish. A terminal window opens at the bottom with the command:

```
heroku create mysite; git push heroku master
```

I then get:

```
Authentication failure
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

If I enter my login details, it says 'Authentication success' but then immediately follows with another authentication failure. This repeats indefinitely.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: After success what you did ?

Comment: After the authentication success I didn't do anything, it just immediately produced another 'Authentication Failure' asking me for my credentials again